Source of Proof of a theorem on Area of Pre-image under a complex polynomial
The following fascinating theorem ,attributed to Polya  is mentioned in the introduction of the paper "The Areas of Polynomial Images and Pre-Images by
Edward Crane" paper link.Could somebody kindly point out some primary  source,or some exposition of it   where we can find its proof .I would be  highly thankful.Here is the theorem: 
P'{o}lya's Inequality:
The area of the pre-image of a closed disc under a monic polynomial $p$ is at most $\pi(\text{Area}(D)/\pi)^{1/n}$, where $D$ is a disc in $\mathbb{C}$.
I would also appreciate if someone could kindly refer me to some further related stuff.

For this, the linked paper refers to G. P´olya, ‘Beitrag zur Verallgemeinerung des Verzerrungssatzes auf mehrfach zusammenh
¨angedende Gebiete’, S-B. Akad. Wiss, Berlin (1928) 228–232, 280–282; reprinted in:
G. P´olya, Collected Papers, vol. 1, Singularities of analytic functions (ed. R. P. Boas,
MIT press, 1974) 352–362.

I have got a soft copy of the book, I could not find the paper at these page numbers .
